# Redirection working only on localhost

Tags: c#, webforms

I'm redirecting to a page using the following instruction but it only works in localhost and when I publish the app in the server i get an error when redirecting

```
Response.Redirect(ResolveClientUrl("employee/employeeSalary.aspx"));
```

Could it be a path problem ?

Comment: Yes, it could. Welcome to stackoverflow. Give more detail if you need a useful answer.

Comment: Yup. What kind of error are you getting exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, paths were not the same on localhost and server

```
Response.Redirect(ResolveClientUrl("~/employee/employeeSalary.aspx"));
```